# Remove Backup Configuration in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backup

I did a backup to a particular database and restore it in another Server. Now I want to remove that backup. But I couldn't remove it. Whenever I remove it, I got the attached error. Could you please advise me how I could delete the backup entry from that database?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming because you're trying to do this from the Backup Database window and hitting `OK` once you've removed the device (thus indicating that you want to perform a backup at this time)

Instead, navigate to "Server Objects", "Backup Devices" in the Object Explorer and remove it from there.

Comment: The "Backup Devices" is empty on my server.